# Using preload-file compiler option for emscripten compiler to load local file in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, webassembly, qmake, emscripten

I am building an Qt Application using WebAssembly. I want to open a local file and read it frin my code which isn't exacty easy with WebAssembly. I tried using the preload-file option ([reference](https://emscripten.org/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html#emcc-preload-file)) in my .pro file:

```
CONFIG += preload-file /path/to/file/Settings.ini
```

However, when compiling my application with WebAssembly, It fails showing my the following error:

```
Application exit (RuntimeError: Aborted(native code called abort()))
```

I am currently using Qt 6 with the fitting Emscripten  version. My code works when compiling with GCC. Of course, emscripten compiles when removing the file handling stuff from my code. Using a file dialog isn't a suitable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you are using `CONFIG +=` but the emscripten reference says it is a linker flag. Try using instead `QMAKE_LFLAGS += --preload-file /path/to/file/Settings.ini`.

Personally, I have not tested preload-file option but two other options have been working for me:

1. The similar embed-file functionality. In the .pro file add `QMAKE_LFLAGS += --embed-file ../../cdpcore/Templates/Models@Models` to make the folder specified to be available in [working directory]/Models.
2. Use the [Qt Resource system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) to embed files. Basically add a .qrc file to your project that lists resources to embed into the binary and then into the .pro file add `RESOURCES += resources.qrc`.

Comment: Thank you, the Qt Resource System was the right thing. I added the .ini file to my .qrc file and now I can access it.